# dynamically adding and removing buttons with jquery

Tags: jquery

New to javascript and jQuery, but I'm trying to dynamically add buttons and then remove them when they are clicked. If a button is there already (in the same class I am creating new buttons), it can be removed. If a new button gets added by the user, that button has no control. I also tried the `.live` method that was mentioned in a similar post to no avail.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> test </title>
  <script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*
      $(document).ready(function(){      
        $(".btn :button").click(function(){
          $(this).remove();
      });
    */
    $(".btn :button").live("click", function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });

    function add() {
      // $(".btn").append("<button> new one </button>");
      $("<button> new one </button>").insertAfter(".btn");
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn">
    <button> test </button>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="adding">
    <button onclick='add()'> add </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

or, if you want to remove the parent container as well:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**UPDATE:**

If you only want buttons inside a specific div, try this:

```
$(".adding button").click(function() {
    $('.adding').before('<div class="btn"><button>new button</button></div>');
});

$(".btn button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but this removes my add button as well.  which exists in a different div.  otherwise, it seems to work, so I am hopeful.  thanks for helping

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work when placed after the .done function but does work when put in the main part of the function.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need a `:` before `button` selector

```
$(".btn button").live("click", function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the response and the votes.  for some reason, this does not work for me.  I tried the same code as first posted without the colon and it still has no effect.  not sure if there is any browser issue, but it did not work with chrome or safari.  and I tried with a hosted version of jquery (from the jquery downloads page) in case mine had a problem, but still nothing.  I will repost if I can figure out the problem